# Iterate through the attribute tables of several SPDFs in R

Tags: shapefile, r, attribute-table

In short I want to know:
What would be the appropriate way to iterate through several SPDFs and do a calculation on every row in their attribute tables?

Some more details: I have some SPDFs and I can iterate through the polygons of each one using something like:

```
x = readOGR(...)
for (i in 1:length(x)){
    x$Volume_Norm[i] <- x$Volume[i]/max(pre_max)
    x$Volume_Sqrt[i] <- sqrt(x$Volume_Norm[i])
    x$Volume_Thrd[i] <- nthroot(x$Volume_Norm[i], 3)
    x$HAZARD_1[i] <- x$Volume_Thrd[i] * x$HAZARD_NEW[i]
  }
```

But I don't know how I could work this into a apply-function or something similar, so that it works on all my SPDFs and I don't have to change the names in the for-loop separately.
If I try:

```
list <- list(x, y, z) # these are my SPDFs
fun <- function(x){
  for (i in 1:length(x)){
    x$Volume_Norm[i] <- x$Volume[i]/max(pre_max)
    x$Volume_Sqrt[i] <- sqrt(x$Volume_Norm[i])
    x$Volume_Thrd[i] <- nthroot(x$Volume_Norm[i], 3)
    x$HAZARD_1[i] <- x$Volume_Thrd[i] * x$HAZARD_NEW[i]
  }
}

lapply(list, fun)
```

nothing changes and I get :

```
> lapply(list, fun)
[[1]]
NULL

[[2]]
NULL

[[3]]
NULL
```

I've asked the same question over at https://stackoverflow.com/q/61549967/11728010, but got no reply so far, so I thought, I could try it here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function doesn't return the modified object. Add `return(x)` and you will get back the modified object, and then `lapply(list,fun)` will return a list of modified objects.

```
fun <- function(x){
  for (i in 1:length(x)){
    x$Volume_Norm[i] <- x$Volume[i]/max(pre_max)
    x$Volume_Sqrt[i] <- sqrt(x$Volume_Norm[i])
    x$Volume_Thrd[i] <- nthroot(x$Volume_Norm[i], 3)
    x$HAZARD_1[i] <- x$Volume_Thrd[i] * x$HAZARD_NEW[i]
  }
return(x)  # <---this
}
```

Then you do:

```
list = lapply(list, fun)
```